# null pointer when accessing getText() on Edit text in alert Dialog

Tags: android

I am trying to create an alert dialog, which contains a text field and a button.
The problem I am facing is, `String str=ets.toString();` on the editText object, it is throwing java.lang.NullPointerException.
Am I missing something?

Java Code:

```
private void newDialog1(Context ct) {
        final View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        ad.setView(v);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout);
        ad.setTitle("Enter Password");
                ad.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Yes clicked");
                        EditText et = (EditText) (v.findViewById(R.id.editText));
                        if (et == null)
                            Log.e(TAG, "Null");
                        else {
                            Editable ets = et.getText();
                            String str=ets.toString();
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                }).create().show();
    }`
```

layout xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/adDialog">



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

 />
```

Comment: get rid of `setContentView(R.layout.layout);` and post the whole stacktrace

Comment: Also, you can just do that in one line `String str=et.getText().toString();

Answer (score 0):

Remove `setContentView(R.layout.layout)`.